# Is it possible to define a function with an all quantified assertion in z3 (with SMT-LIB2 interface)?

Tags: z3

My goal is to define a function, which takes an input integer sequence and outputs an integer sequence with **the same length**, but **containing only the first element of the input** sequence. For example (in pseudo-code):

```
f([7,5,6]) = [7,7,7]
```

For this I declare a function in `z3` as:

```
(declare-fun f ((Seq Int)) (Seq Int))
```

and try to force the expected behavior with the assertion:

```
(assert 
    (forall ((arr (Seq Int)))
        (and
            (=
                (seq.len arr)
                (seq.len (f arr))
            )
            (forall ((i Int))
                (implies
                    (and
                        (>= i 0)
                        (< i (seq.len arr))
                    )
                    (=
                        (seq.at arr 0)
                        (seq.at (f arr) i)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ))
```

The problem is that the program does not terminate, which I suspect is caused by the all-quantifier. To test whether my conditions are correct I declared two constants and saw that for **concrete** values the conditions are correct:

```
(define-const first (Seq Int)
    (seq.++ (seq.unit 1) (seq.unit 2))
)
(declare-const second (Seq Int))
(assert 
    (and
        (=
            (seq.len first)
            (seq.len second)
        )
        (forall ((i Int))
            (implies
                (and
                    (>= i 0)
                    (< i (seq.len first))
                )
                (=
                    (seq.at first 0)
                    (seq.at second i)
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

**My question:** How would it be possible to integrate the conditions in the assertions with the expected behavior of the `f` function? The function should be total, which means it should be defined for all possible input sequences, but this leads me to think that an all quantifier is definitely needed in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reasoning with such recursive data-types/values is not a strong suit for SMT solvers. Most problems will require induction and SMT-solvers don't do induction out-of-the box.

Having said that, you can code what you want using the new `declare-fun-rec` construct:

```
(define-fun-rec copyHeadAux ((x (Seq Int)) (l (Seq Int))) (Seq Int)
   (ite (= 0 (seq.len l))
        (as seq.empty (Seq Int))
    (seq.++ x (copyHeadAux x (seq.extract l 1 (seq.len l))))))


(define-fun copyHead ((l (Seq Int))) (Seq Int)
   (ite (= 0 (seq.len l))
        (as seq.empty (Seq Int))
    (copyHeadAux (seq.at l 0) l)))

(define-fun test () (Seq Int) (seq.++ (seq.unit 7) (seq.unit 5) (seq.unit 6)))
(declare-const out (Seq Int))
(assert (= out (copyHead test)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

When I run this, I get:

```
sat
(
  (define-fun out () (Seq Int)
    (seq.++ (seq.unit 7) (seq.unit 7) (seq.unit 7)))
  (define-fun test () (Seq Int)
    (seq.++ (seq.unit 7) (seq.unit 5) (seq.unit 6)))
  (define-fun copyHead ((x!0 (Seq Int))) (Seq Int)
    (ite (= 0 (seq.len x!0))
         (as seq.empty (Seq Int))
         (copyHeadAux (seq.at x!0 0) x!0)))
)
```

which is the correct answer you're looking for. But unless your constraints only involve "constant-folding" cases (i.e., where `copyHead` is always applied to a constant known value), you're likely to get `unknown` as the answer, or have the solver go into an infinite e-matching loop.

It's best to use a proper theorem prover (Isabelle, HOL, Lean, ACL2 etc.) for reasoning with these sorts of recursive definitions. Of course, SMT solvers get better over time and maybe one day they'll be able to handle more problems like this out-of-the-box, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: Is it possible to prove certain characteristics of the function? For example `copyHead(a) == copyHead(copyHead(a))`

When I add this assert in the end, the code cannot terminate. I was wondering whether I could formulate it in a way that z3 outputs sat:

`(assert
 (forall ((a (Seq Int)))
  (=
   (copyHead a) 
   (copyHead (copyHead a))
  )
 )
)

(check-sat)`

Comment: That doesn't surprise me. As I mentioned in my answer unless `copyHead` is always applied to a constant value, it's very unlikely `z3` or any other solver willl ever prove the theorem you want out-of-the-box. Think about how you'd prove it by hand: By induction on the structure (i.e., length) of the sequence. SMT solvers don't do induction. If this is your goal, you're much better off using a proper theorem prover. (Most have `smt` tactics to discharge subgoals anyhow these days.)