# Is it possible to prove this defined function is an involution in z3?

Tags: z3, smt

I'm trying to understand how to define an assertion in such a way that it proves certain mathematical qualities of an already defined function. As discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65906297/is-it-possible-to-define-a-function-with-an-all-quantified-assertion-in-z3-with) SMT solvers are not well-suited for induction, which is often needed to prove a mathematical quality.

In my case, I have a recursive function definition for the **identity function** `f(x) = x` (just as a simple example):

```
(define-fun-rec identity-rec ((l String)) String
   (ite (= 0 (str.len l))
      ""
      (str.++ (str.at l 0) (identity-rec (str.substr l 1 (seq.len l))))))



(define-fun identity ((l String)) String
   (ite (= 0 (str.len l))
      ""
      (identity-rec l)))
```

[The same post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65906297/is-it-possible-to-define-a-function-with-an-all-quantified-assertion-in-z3-with) suggests that such characteristics cannot be proven out-of-the-box. However, I am interested to know how general mathematical properties are proven in `z3`. I tried with all-quantifiers to prove the **involution** of the function but `z3` does not terminate:

```
(assert
(forall ((a String))
    (=
        a
        (indentity (identity a))
    )
)
```

**My Question:**
What assertion can we use to prove that such a recursive function is an involution with `z3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really much you can do here. Ideally, the strategy would be to define and prove the base case and the inductive-step separately, and then argue (at the meta-level) that the property is true for all strings.

For the base-case things are easy enough. I'd define:

```
(define-fun check-inv ((x String)) Bool (= (identity (identity x)) x))

(define-fun base_case () Bool (check-inv ""))
```

And then:

```
(assert (not base_case))
```

If you do this, z3 will happily say `unsat`, i.e., base case is true. For the induction step, I'd define:

```
(define-fun inductive_step () Bool
   (forall ((x String) (c String))
        (implies (and (= 1 (str.len c)) (check-inv x))
                 (check-inv (str.++ c x)))))
```

And hope to prove:

```
(assert (not inductive_step))
```

Alas, you'll find that z3 will choke on this query, i.e., won't terminate. Assuming for a second it did, you'd then conclude (at the meta-level) that `identity` is indeed an involution. But this has to be done at one-level above z3; either by a human, or some other proof tool that uses z3 as a sub-engine.

So, the natural question is to ask what are the hopes for getting z3 to prove the `inductive_step`? It will definitely not do it out-of-the-box. But perhaps you can use patterns to coax it into doing so, see https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h28 for details. Be warned, however, that even if you can get this proof go with very clever pattern instantiations, the proof will be so very brittle: Even minor changes to your theorem or the actual implementation of z3 can affect the result, as you'll be at the mercy of a myriad of heuristics.

Long story short: You're using the wrong tool if your goal is to prove properties of recursive functions. Use ACL2, HOL, Isabelle, etc.; which *are* purposefully *designed* and *built* to deal with such theorems. An SMT solver just doesn't fit the bill here.